# two-level index ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

Is it possible to create index of structure like this:

```
localhost:9200/shopname/products/product
```

where "shopname/products" is composite index, and "product" is type?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to create an index with a slash in it, precisely because the correct URL handler wouldn't be triggered.

I don't think you really need it here.  You can either use a prefix on the index, like `shopname-products/product/1234`, or just comingle the relevant data for shopname with `shopname/products/1234`.